# What's the best way to get numerical values from those strings

Tags: java, android, casting

I have serveral strings like this one "20160621060000", which actually is a date:

Year: 2016, Month: 06, Day:21, Hour: 06, Minute:00, Seconds: 00

I need to split it like how i did above and save this data, but I'm having troubles cause the casted value of "20160621060000" to Double is too big so i'm getting a casted value like this one: 2.01606210515E13 (what actually happened here?)

this is my code

```
Double StartValue = Double.parseDouble(StartDate);
System.out.println(StartValue);
```

Also i can't do

```
int Year = Startvalue/10000000000
```

(10^10) cause i get  "integer number too large"
Can someone help me find a way to do that?

Comment: `long Year` instead of `int Year`.

Comment: Do you really need it in discrete variables, or just as a `Date`?

Comment: I actually have a Date class, but i tought it were irrelevant

Comment: Do u really have to use the string like this? The normal way to get a moment in time representation in a single value is to use Linux epoch. That is amount of miliseconds since 1st-Jan-1970. You can get that with `System.currentTimeMillis()` and it's a standard. With that value you can build a `Date` or `GregorianCalendar` to operate on the individual values.

Comment: those strings are parsed from a xmlfile obtained from a webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Long.parseLong(StartDate);` instead `Double.parseDouble(StartDate);`

Comment: Worked! thaks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use BigDecimal instead of double.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is too large you should use long instead of int.

If this number is a date, you can use SimpleDateFormatter https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss");
String daytime = formatter.format(yourDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use Format to convert into Data:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
Date date = formatter.parse("2016 06 21 06 00 00");
```

For further information use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) link.